# How to get started with WebRTC?

Tags: webrtc

I am a beginner with WebRTC, and I would like to know if there is anything I need to import to use the JavaScript APIs.

Comment: The answer is simple write the same thing on Google and see what you get!!! I got this when I typed your question on google:- http://www.webrtc.org/reference/getting-started Hope this helps!!!

Comment: But I am going to use Javascript. The source code provided in that site is in C. How do I import that into my Javascript file, or do I even need to import anything?

Comment: When I started, I found this article the easiest: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/

Comment: I read through that as well, but my question is, do I need to import anything to my Javascript file to make everything work? For example, when I call pc = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration); I get a console error saying Uncaught ReferenceError: RTCPeerConnection is not defined.

Comment: Well done Sam, Please add your resoutce as an answer. It answers the question nicely.

Comment: This one may help: http://muaz-khan.blogspot.com/2013/12/getting-started-with-webrtc-guide-for.html

Comment: Do i need an external server in order to use webrtc? I' m like im missing the big picture of this. How it works the nat traversal?

Comment: Rahul's link is no longer valid. Try this: https://webrtc.org/start/

Comment: You can try peer js, It simplifies WebRTC for you.
you can check this demo for it, [link](https://github.com/Abhi5h3k/WebRTC-PeerJs-Demo)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you do not need to import any library. webRTC is included in Chrome and Firefox (and for Chrome beta and Firefox on Android).

Your error may be because you need to prefix it with `webkit` like this:

```
peer = new webkitRTCPeerConnection(...)
```

Comment: And mozRTCPeerConnection() on Firefox, until the spec is more complete.  See the polyfill linked from webrtc.org and used in http://apprtc.appspot.com

Answer (score 2):

You don't *need* to include anything to use WebRTC's APIs, but as a practical matter, you will probably *want* to use an adapter to normalize API naming differences between browser vendors (e.g. webkitGetUserMedia/mozGetuserMedia).

Google maintains a nice adapter that does this, and handles a few gotcha errors you might run into if using them directly.

Just include the following script in your page.

https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/source/browse/trunk/samples/js/base/adapter.js